# Is the 2018 Survey results page not working for anyone else?

Tags: bug, status-reproduced, survey-2018, insights

I'm getting:

> Error. An error occurred while processing your request.

every time I try to hit the [results page](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey/2018).

The other URLs on "insights" work fine.

I'm using Chrome on a Macbook.

Comment: Works for me, even on FireFox Nightly!

Comment: No repro for me on Chrome/Win10

Comment: FYI Please interpret down-votes as "no I don't have this problem" rather than "this is a bad question": Meta is a bit different than the other side of SO :).

Comment: Can you try a different browser/network/ISP? So you can rule out any local issues? And in case this is caused by a downstream CDN provider, what is roughly your location in the world?

Comment: Awesome. This indicates it's some problem local to me or my ISP, or work networking, and not OS/Browser dependent. Location is Mountain View, CA, USA.

Comment: I'm running Chrome on a macbook and it isn't working for me either.

Comment: It's sporadic. I have see the error right now, Firefox, OS X, and I'm in the UK. Probably one or two machines in a cluster that are b0rken. A fellow moderator saw it earlier, and currently it is working for them, but not me.

Comment: I have the same error in Chrome on Windows 7.

Comment: No, on two separate networks

Comment: It was broken for me yesterday, but today it's working

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We had a low-level issue affecting one of our web servers that was causing some users trying to access the page to receive 500 errors. The issue has since been addressed and we're still looking into the root cause. Sorry for any inconvenience and please let us know if you experience any additional issues!

Comment: Was meta the right place to report this, or is there some preferred support email address I should use in the future? Thanks for the update, and the fix.

Comment: Meta is fine, @JesseM - thanks for the report!

Answer (score 2):

OP here. Like one of the comments above, it was failing for me all day yesterday, and is now working today from the same location/browser/OS.

Thanks to whomever fixed whatever was wrong. Looks like I wasn't the only one seeing it, but that it was scattered.